# Kernel loading forever in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using OSX Yosemite.

I've update ipython via conda and turns out notebook also has updated version, which I'm very excited to try this.The notebook has been converted into jupyter.

I'm using python 2.X, and already have existing .ipynb files. When I open it, new window appears but there's blank and nothing. I can create first cell there, but I already have my notebook. And the kernel also loading forever. There isn't any error log in the console. What do I have to do? Please help!

Comment: Try with `ipython notebook --debug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, this solve the problem https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5746

I'm using ccp notebook extension, and as Ian Hawke mentioned in the thread, remove the call to the extention at profile/static/custom/custom.js